# Is it possible to run a NodeJS server while the Mac display is off or the Mac is locked?

Tags: node.js, macos

I'm running a Node JS server on my Mac.  I want to lock the Mac and/or put it to sleep but keep the Node process running.  Is that possible?  How do I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: How about just try it and see what happens?  Start it up, leave the Mac for awhile and then try to connect to it.  It will probably be fine.

Comment: I did.  It isn't.  If it were, I wouldn't have asked the question.  If it should be, then that's helpful to know that it's something in my code.

Comment: Add an ampersand (&) after the command you're using to launch it.